# Not able to reach the service url of the local kubernetes cluster in docker desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

On calling kubectl get service, I am able to see external ip as localhost and the port as 5555:32316.

[image]

But the i am not able to reach the url localhost:5555 from browser.

Also curl `http://localhost:5555` is giving this error :

```
curl : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

What is missing here.

Comment: It seems the LoadBalancer service does not have any problems, Are you sure the pod behind service is working properly?

Comment: @Xirehat Testing it out using a HelloWorld app. Is there a way to check if that service is running fine ?